# ASP.MVC GroupBy

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq, model-view-controller, group-by

I have to entites and i try group by them, but i cant get it to work.

When I run it I get the following error, I think it's because I try to parse GroupBy to a ToDictionary(), see the controller method. But in the view it uses IEnumerable. In some way I need to parse Dictionary to the view. But I don't know how.

Do you have some ideas how can I get this solved?

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type:
>   `System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[System.String,System.Int32]]`
>
> but this dictionary requires a model item of type:
>
> `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[aProejct.Models.Database.Properties]`.

Here I have my Controller method:

```
    public ActionResult Test()
    {
        var group = db.Propertiess.AsNoTracking().GroupBy(x => x.PropertiesName).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());


        return View(group.ToList());
    }
```

And my view

```
model IEnumerable<aProject.Models.Database.Properties>

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
    </p>

    <ul>
        @foreach (var group in Model.GroupBy(item => item.PropertiesName)) { 

        <li>
            @Html.Encode(group.Key)
            <ul>

               @foreach (var item in group)
               {
                <li>
                    @Html.Encode(item.SubPropertiess)
                </li>
              } 

            </ul>
        </li>

       }
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: error is at your view side. try to manage it like @model List<aProject.Models.Database.Properties>.

Comment: if still it gives error, just focus on your group variable and then whatever type comes, add it to model in view.

Comment: thx, i will try :)

Comment: you also shouldn't really need to be doing GroupBy in your view, since you're already grouping the items in your controller action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller you are doing `.ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());` which returns a KeyValue dictionary where the Key is the `PropertiesName` and the Value is the number of entries matched for that group.

I don't really think this is what you want. You are not actually passing the items in these groups, to the view in any way.

`g` is actually an enumerable containing your Properties, so you would need to also make sure this is passed on to the view in order to iterate through them.

*edit:* From what it looks like in your code - you're not really using the `Count` anyway. Try passing your `g` (containing the items in the group) as the value instead of doing the `Count()`. Then you should be able to use something like `List<string, IEnumerable<Property>>` for your model in your view.

If you actually do need the Count later on, you can just do a Count on the value, in your view.

I would however suggest looking into creating a real viewmodel class for your view, where everything the view may need can be set by the controller, to keep your view as simple as possible.